# Best way to configure truffle `from` address

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm setting up my truffle config file and I'm setting the `from` address from an env variable like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    local: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      from: process.env.OWNER,
    }
  }
};
```

Then I run `OWNER=<address> truffle migrate --network local`

Any suggestions on a better way to do this, to get truffle to use the first address generated by ganache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit the `from` parameter in your `truffle.cfg`, it will automatically default to the first account returned by `web3.eth.getAccounts` from the provider you're connected to.

If you want more dynamic control over the account used, you can control this with the [deployer](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer).

```
var SimpleContract = artifacts.require("SimpleContract");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleContract, { from: accounts[1] }); // Deploy contract from the 2nd account in the list
  deployer.deploy(SimpleContract, { from: accounts[2] }); // Deploy the same contract again (different address) from the 3rd account.
};
```

Of course, you don't have to use the account list passed in and you can pull in a list from any other data source you want. You can also use `network` if you want to have environment specific logic.